# When I change one project in a solution, several other projects are rebuilt

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, build-process

I have a large Visual Studio 2010 solution with many C# projects in it.

When I

1. build the solution,
2. then change one project in it (add a couple of `Console.WriteLine` statements) and
3. build it again,

not only the changed project is compiled, but several others as well (`compile complete` messages appears 12 times in the build output).

What may cause this behaviour (change in one project leads to recompilation of several others), except dependencies between the projects ?

Comment: depends (pun intended) on what you call 'dependencies'.. You can set dependencies directly in the `Project Dependencies` dialog, or indirectly by adding project references under a project's `References` item group..

Comment: I just figured out that the project I change isn't referenced by any other project in the solution.